# mongoose mapReduce by gender and area

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce

I am trying to use the mapReduce method to get the count of men and women staying in a specific area. I am using the following code and then I write a logic to count the values. Was wondering if this could be done within the module. Is this possible or my existing approach is the way to do it

```
module.export.findStudentsForGivenAdministrativeAreaInAState = function(administrativeArea){
var o = {};
var self = this;
o.map = function () {
    var values = {gender:this.gender,area_level_2:this.address.administrative_area_level_2};
    emit(this._id, values)
};
o.reduce = function (k, vals) {
    return vals;
};
o.query = {
    'address.administrative_area_level_1': administrativeArea
};

return new Promise.resolve(Student.mapReduce(o))
    .then(function (data) {
        return data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        routesLogger.logError("studentDAL", "getDistinctStatesWhereStudentsAreRegistered", error);
        return error;
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the expected result? Do you specify specific area with the field 'administrative_area_level_2'?

Comment: I do specify the field as an agrument to the export. I am passing administrativeArea.  If I had say 2 distinct administrative_area_level_2 I was hoping to get                                                                                     [ {_id :xxxx, area_level_2 : "District1" , men:2,women:2,count:4},           {_id :xxxx, area_level_2 : "District2" , men:4,women:4,count:8} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done using the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/)**, which has better performance since aggregation runs natively in the server (C++), whereas mapReduce spawns separate javascript thread(s) to run JavaScript code. You can thus run the following **[`aggregation`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** pipeline to achieve the same result:

```
var Student = require('../../../models/Student');
module.exports.findStudentsForGivenAdministrativeAreaInAState = function(administrativeArea, callback){
    var pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": { "address.administrative_area_level_1": administrativeArea }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$address.administrative_area_level_2",
                "men": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$gender", "male" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                "women": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$gender", "female" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        }
    ];

    Student.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, results) {
        if(err) { callback(err); }
        else {
            console.log(results);
            callback(null, results);
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: @RahulGanguly No worries. What is the issue?